# Pass an arbitrary set of paired parameters, where one of the pair items needs to be an arbitrary datatype

Tags: vb.net, object, tuples, parameter-passing

I have a function to which I want to pass an arbitrary number of paired parameters (i.e. a `String` variable and a second arbitrary type (could be a `String`, `Integer` etc.) - hence am declaring the second half of the pair as an `Object`. There could be one or more pairs of this nature.

The most obvious structure I could think of for this was therefore a `Tuple(Of String, Object)`

Here is the function :

```vb
Private Function TableLookup(
        table As DataTable,
        ByVal columnNamesAndKeys As List(Of Tuple(Of String, Object)),
        resultColumnName As String) As Object

    Dim filterExpression As String = ""
    For i = 0 To columnNamesAndKeys.Count
        Dim lookupColumn As String = columnNamesAndKeys(i).Item1
        Dim lookupKey As Object = columnNamesAndKeys(i).Item2
        Dim keyType = lookupKey.GetType()
        If keyType IsNot table.Columns(lookupColumn).DataType Then Return Nothing
        If keyType Is GetType(String) Then
            filterExpression += IIf(Len(filterExpression) > 0, " AND ", "") + $"{lookupColumn} = '{lookupKey}'"
        ElseIf keyType Is GetType(Date) Then
            filterExpression += IIf(Len(filterExpression) > 0, " AND ", "") + $"{lookupColumn} = #{lookupKey:M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt}#"
        Else
            filterExpression += IIf(Len(filterExpression) > 0, " AND ", "") + $"{lookupColumn} = {lookupKey}"
        End If
    Next
    Dim row = table.Select(filterExpression).FirstOrDefault()
    Return If(row Is Nothing, Nothing, row(resultColumnName))
End Function
```

Called thus (for a single pair) :

```vb
Dim someKey As Integer
Dim someValue = TableLookup(
    dtbSomeTable,
    New List(Of Tuple(Of String, Object))
       From {("SomeKey", DirectCast(someKey, Object)).ToTuple},
    "SomeOtherColumn")
```

And thus (for multiple pairs) :

```vb
Dim someKey As Integer
Dim someOtherKey As String
Dim someValue = TableLookup(
    dtbSomeTable,
    New List(Of Tuple(Of String, Object))
        From {("SomeKey", DirectCast(someKey, Object)).ToTuple,
              ("SomeOtherKey", DirectCast(someOtherKey, Object)).ToTuple},
    "SomeOtherColumn")
```

So - this *works* - but it feels awfully clunky calling it each time, having to create an ad-hoc list of `Tuples`, then declare each `Tuple` and `DirectCast` each key as an `Object` to obey the strongly-typed requirement.

The whole point of the function was to provide an easy one-liner throughout the code to quickly look up columns with potentially multiple, arbitrary, criteria but all of these manipulations within the call makes it less intelligible to anyone unfortunate enough to ever have to maintain this...

Is there a smarter / cleaner way to pass an arbitrary set of paired parameters, where one of the pair items needs to be an arbitrary `Type`?

Comment: `IEnumerable(Of T)` has variance, but I'm not sure it would reach all the way into a tuple.  That is, I'm sure you can provide an `IEnumerable(Of MyType)` to an argument declared of `IEnumerable(Of Object)`.  Unless you specifically need indexed access to the list, I'd recommend preferring `IEnumerable` to `List`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, recommend to replace use of the `IIf` function with the `If` ternary operator.  I note that there is a use of the `If` operator to return from the function.

Comment: Don't use a list of tuples. Use a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney - my initial lean was to use a `Dictionary` also but I thought I was going to run into a similar issue declaring a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` and then trying to apply a `String` or `Integer` as the `Value` half of the pair but having now tested it, it works fine (and _so_ much cleaner)

Comment: Thanks @Craig - just to clarify, are you recommending `IIf` over `If` or `If` over `IIf` ?

Comment: Recommend `If` over `IIf`.  The latter was a library function added to cover for the lack of the former in the VBA-heritage versions of the language and even I think early versions of .NET-heritage VB (and thus persists in later versions of .NET for compatibility reasons).  Because it's a library function, it can't do short-circuiting and it doesn't have any type safety.

Comment: `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` is great - as long as the keys are unique. `IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of String, Object))` or `IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Object))` doesn't have the same requirement

Comment: @djv Why, exactly? I don't want a `DataRow`, I want an atomic value from a specific column in a specific row per a criteria, why would I return the whole row and then have to identify the expected value within it? The keys are unique because they are the names of the lookup columns; these are inherently unique by the conditions of the DataTable and you would have no reason to lookup two different values on the same column?

Comment: @AlanO'Brien right, I read the code incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using a [Parameter Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/parameter-arrays) (`ParamArray` ) in conjunction with  [value tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples). This allows you to call the method easily with any number of parameters and no explicit list or array instantiation and neither a `New` keyword for the values nor any casts. Note that we must swap `columnNamesAndKeys` and `resultColumnName`, since the `ParamArray` used to pass `columnNamesAndKeys` must be the last parameter of the method.

Usage example:

```vb
Dim result = TableLookup(
    dtbSomeTable,
    "ResultColumn",
    ("id", 12), ("name", "Joe"), ("date", #2022/10/28#), ("someKey", someValue))
```

The adapted function:

```vb
Private Function TableLookup(
    table As DataTable,
    resultColumnName As String,
    ParamArray columnNamesAndKeys() As (key As String, value As Object)
) As Object

    Dim filterExpression As String = ""
    For i = 0 To columnNamesAndKeys.Length - 1
        Dim lookupColumn As String = columnNamesAndKeys(i).key
        Dim lookupKey As Object = columnNamesAndKeys(i).value
        Dim keyType = lookupKey.GetType()
        If keyType IsNot table.Columns(lookupColumn).DataType Then Return Nothing
        If filterExpression.Length > 0 Then
            filterExpression += " AND "
        End If
        If keyType Is GetType(String) Then
            filterExpression += $"{lookupColumn} = '{DirectCast(lookupKey, String).Replace("'", "''")}'"
        ElseIf keyType Is GetType(Date) Then
            filterExpression += $"{lookupColumn} = #{lookupKey:yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt}#"
        Else
            filterExpression += $"{lookupColumn} = {lookupKey}"
        End If
    Next
    Dim row = table.Select(filterExpression).FirstOrDefault()
    Return If(row Is Nothing, Nothing, row(resultColumnName))
End Function
```

I also did some refactorings.

- Since I used a named tuple, you can access the fields by name instead of just `Item1` or `Item2'.
- Conditionally adding the `" AND "` part can be done once before the lengthy If Then Else ...
- I replace any single quotes within a string value by two single quotes. E.g., a string like `"John's Pub"` becomes `'John''s Pub'` in SQL notation.
- `For i = 0 To columnNamesAndKeys.Count` is wrong. The index goes from `0` to `Count - 1`. And since we have an array now, we must use `Length`.

Comment: This doesn't work. The generic T will be a single type, not multiple types as the OP needs. The idea is good, to enable the passing of the tuples like this: `{("SomeKey", someKey), ("SomeOtherKey", someOtherKey)}` (well, if we change the IEnumerable instead of List) but then the method needs a single T as the tuple's second generic parameter. If you allow OP to pass as he is originally with Objects, then `GetType(T)` is always Object and this fails.

Comment: OP returns `Object` because I don't know in advance the datatype of the column from which the value is being returned? It could be a `String`, it could be an `Integer`, it could be a `Boolean`...

Comment: Okay, I completely revised my answer.